# Kendo MVC Grid preventDefault() did not stop fire create event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

What I had is a simple grid, using popup edit.

The edit uses an editortemplate (in cshtml / razor), which has an Kendo Upload Control.

What I want to achieve is that when user click the update button of the popup window, it triggers the upload control (to start async upload files) and **AFTER THAT** the grid would fire the normal event which post to controller create action.

The problem I am facing is, the normal grid create event is always fired before the async upload finishes.

The following is my javascript snippet (which fails)

```js
function onAttachmentRequestStart(e) {
        if (e.type == "create") {
            e.preventDefault();  // Attempt to stop fire create event
            var grid = $("#WorkOrderAttachmentGrid").data("kendoGrid"); // get my grid
            grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) { 
                e.preventDefault();   // prevent popup window closing
                $("#AddAttachmentForm .k-button.k-upload-selected").click(); // This is the hidden button of the upload control, manual trigger click to start async upload
            });
        }
    }
```

I attempted to cancel / stop the normal grid create event by the first `e.preventDefault()` and was thinking to manual trigger it at the success event of the Upload control. but clearly it fails.

How can I implement such feature described? 
Please tell me if anything I can provide that helps.

Comment: when is your `onAttachmentRequestStart` triggered